# iccOpenLogicalChannel returns STATUS_NO_SUCH_ELEMENT on Javacard Applet

Tags: android, javacard, sim-card

I have an applet (taken from [this HelloSTK2 repo](https://github.com/mrlnc/HelloSTK2)) I've compiled and installed on a SysmoISIM-SJA2 card and I've lightly modified it to respond to a SELECT APDU. The modification looks like this:

```
public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
    showHello();
}
private void showHello() {
    ProactiveHandler proHdlr = ProactiveHandler.getTheHandler();
    proHdlr.initDisplayText((byte)0, DCS_8_BIT_DATA, welcomeMsg, (short)0, 
            (short)(welcomeMsg.length));
    proHdlr.send();
    return;
}
```

All I did was move the existing `showHello()` function to the function that handles APDUs. It's my understanding from the Javacard documentation that the `process()` function should run and then return a status word of 9000, or an error code if applicable.

To `SELECT` the file I have an Android application I've written that uses `iccOpenLogicalChannel` and takes the AID as an argument. Using GlobalPlatformPro I can see that the applet is installed properly on the UICC and that it is listed as `SELECTABLE`, however when I run my Android application I get a `STATUS_NO_SUCH_ELEMENT` response which according to the [iccOpenLogicalChannelResponse source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse.java) means the AID is not found on the UICC.

The code for the Android app is very simple and looks like this:

```
val inputView: EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.AID_INPUT)
            val input: String = inputView.text.toString()
            val ch = mTelephonyManager.iccOpenLogicalChannel(input)
            Toast.makeText(this, ch.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            mTelephonyManager.iccCloseLogicalChannel(ch.channel)
```

and the output of listing the applets on the card looks like this (truncated):

```
AID: d07002ca44, State: 01, Privs: 00
Instance AID: d07002ca44900102
```

I've tried both d07002ca44 and d07002ca44900102 and get the same response for both AIDs.

My question then: what steps do I need to take to ensure this applet is able to be selected by my Android application?

Worth noting probably that my Android app does have carrier privileges and I'm able to send APDUs to other applications such as the USIM and ISIM applets.

Comment: I'd expect that the logical channel is not available rather than the AID. I did a very brief check and it seems that they are optional for SIM cards as well. You can simply use the base channel, but that's opened without any specific command such as `iccOpenLogicalChannel `.

Comment: I thought that might be the case but the error message does explicitly say that the UICC can't be found, and I'd assume I'd receive the STATUS_MISSING_RESOURCE error if it were just that the channel can't be opened. I will try with the basic channel though and report back. Thanks!